# Can gaming damage my MacBook Air in the long run?

Tags: macbook-pro, games

I noticed my new MacBook Air getting kinda hot and the fan spinning up when running a 3D game. I know this Laptop is not made for gaming but I like to run a less demanding game from time to time. Also I'm not crazy and wouldn't do this in a already hot environment but technically it should not degrade the Laptop in the long run am I right?

Comment: Didn't see that one sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got nothing to worry about. They're designed to handle it. Heat in general does degrade computers, but the laptop will be very, very obsolete before the extra heat generated from gaming adds up enough to matter.

Comment: That's good to know. One of the reasons I buy an Apple product is because I expect quality.